# Dual boot Win11+Ubuntu/Kubuntu Lenovo X13 AMD

Tags: dual-boot, windows

Have a Lenovo X13 AMD Notebook and trying the second day to install Kubuntu (prefered) or Ubuntu ad dual boot aside Win 11.
One OS only works fine in any case --> tried.

I can install Ubuntu/Kubuntu, but when i try to start Ubuntu/Kubuntu after installation in the UEFI it is just doing nothing. Really nothing. Because I can start Windows Boot Manger normally after I tried to start Ubuntu/Kubuntu.

Has somebody any idea, what I should change?

TPM2.0 and secure boot activated. Any change does not affect starting Ubuntu/Kubuntu, still can not start. Windows 11 starts any way.

Thanks for inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Because I didn't get any answer, I tried some things.
This is how it works (for me, only with a fresh install):

- Delete/format whole HDD
- delet all entries in UEFI --> set factory default
- install (K)ubuntu with secure boot
- set secure boot off (because of Windows 11 installation media and because of hibernation in (K)ubuntu
- install Windows 11 Pro
- in UEFI set ubuntu as default in boot order
- set timeout in Grub (10 seconds)

done! Have fun

Comment: Windows 11 requires Secure Boot ON and it has nothing to do with hibernation in Kubuntu.